NoResourceFoundException: No static resource but it exists in resources/static
I have recently been practicing using Thymeleaf with Spring Boot and connecting to a MySQL database.But however, I get some problems with it.
before I tried to insert data into the MySQL database using Spring Boot(I added data to the table.), the page was displaying correctly. However, after attempting to add data, the page shows a Whitelabel Error Page.
here is the error I got:
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Oct 05 23:04:04 CST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found. status=404).
No static resource templates/products/create.
org.springframework.web.servdet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource templates/products/create.

I use XAMPP to manage MySQL, and I am not sure is it a port problem?
I really feel so confuse it.
Here is my directory structure:
src
└── main
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── boostnytool
    │           └── bestStore
    │               ├── controllers
    │               │   └── ProductsController.java
    │               ├── models
    │               │   └── Product.java
    │               └── services
    │                   └── ProductRepository.java
    │               └── BestStoreApplication.java
    └── resources
        ├── static
        │   └── images
        │       ├── 11736965.jpg
        │       ├── 57380538.jpg
        │       ├── 80522267.jpg
        │       └── 97815739.jpg
        ├── index_first.html
        └── templates
            └── products
                └── index.html
        └── application.properties

And there is my code:
ProductsController

package com.boostmytool.bestStore.controllers;

import com.boostmytool.bestStore.models.Product;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.boostmytool.bestStore.services.ProductRepository;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductsController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository repo;

    @GetMapping({"","/"})
    public  String showProductList(Model model){
        List<Product> products = repo.findAll();
        // 打印產品列表到控制台
        System.out.println(products);

        // 打印每個產品的 imageFileName 以進一步檢查
        for (Product product : products) {
            System.out.println("Product ID: " + product.getId() + ", Image File Name: " + product.getImageFileName());
        }
        model.addAttribute("products",products);
        return "products/index";
    }
}

Product
package com.boostmytool.bestStore.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "templates/products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private String category;
    private double price;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;
    private Date createdAt;
    private String imageFileName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getImageFileName() {
        return imageFileName;
    }

    public void setImageFileName(String imageFileName) {
        this.imageFileName = imageFileName;
    }
}

ProductRepository
package com.boostmytool.bestStore.services;

import com.boostmytool.bestStore.models.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {
}

index_first.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center my-4">welcome to our website </h1>

    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/templates/products">products</a>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Best Store</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center my-4">Products</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/templates/products/create">Create Product</a>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
            <td th:text="${product.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.brand}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.category}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.price} + '$'"></td>
            <td>
                <img th:src="@{/images/{fileName}(fileName=${product.imageFileName})}" alt="Product Image" width="100">
            </td>
            <td th:text="${product.createdAt.toString().substring(0, 10)}"></td>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" th:href="@{/products/edit(id=${product.id})}">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" th:href="@{/products/delete(id=${product.id})}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

application.properties
spring.application.name=bestStore

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/beststore
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=springboot
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.boostmytool</groupId>
    <artifactId>bestStore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bestStore</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- sql -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I tried to find out if there was a typo in the connection names, and I also checked the application.properties file, but the problem was not resolved.

Is there a handler/endpoint for templates/products/create?

Xampp replaced mysql with mariadb years ago and, the two of them are not the same. The error message in the title does not suggest there is anything wrong with database, so removed mysql tag and did not add mariadb.

@dan1st I haven't completed it yet, and the problem is showing up.

@Shadow If I remove XAMPP, do I need to add the MySQL tags again?

@Suuu well the problem seems literally that endpoint being missing - that's what the error tells you

And if you think the DBMS is relevant.(like if you think there would be an issue with SQL queries), you can add the tag of the DBMS you are actually using.

@Suuu not sure what you mean by removing xampp having an impact on adding mysql tag back. The issue does not seem to be with the database.

guys!! I know what's wrong!!! I didn't get/set name!!! now my page can show the list, thank u guys!!!

very very very thank you to give me advice.

The error says:

No static resource templates/products/create.

I think you requested http://localhost/products/create.
URLs you mapped are http://localhost/products or http://localhost/products/.
You have to request http://localhost/products or http://localhost/products/.

thank ur comment! I find where i get wrong , I didn't add get/set  name, now it can work. I can't believe I took four days to fix this problem
